# post form in node.js testing with postman vs browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, formidable

I am posting a form to node.js server with postman chrome tool which works
 fine and shows the result as follows

```
{"username":"dagimasdsdaa","password":"dagimpassmea"}
```

but using my browser with html markup as shown below it doesn't post correctly  and outputs

> {"username":"","password":""}

can't figure out why ? any help?

```
itemsRouter.route('/login')
    .post(function(req,res){

        // `file` is the name of the <input> field of type `file`
        var formdata={'username':'','password':''};
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields) {
            formdata.username=fields.username;
            formdata.password=fields.password;

        });
        res.json(formdata);
        res.end();

    });
```

my html markup looks like this,which seems to be fine form me

```
                  <form  action="/login" method="post">
                            <div >
                                <div class="form-group"  style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control"   name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <br/>
                            </div>

                            <div >
                                <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 8px;margin-right: 14px" class="btn btn-facebook pull-right">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: what content type you are using during postman ?

Comment: 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--

Answer (score 0):

Found out i didn't set enctype for the html which the browser takes it as

> 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

by default but i have parsed the form as

> enctype='multipart/form-data'

so the final html markup will look like this

```
<form  action="/login" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
                            <div >
                                <div class="form-group"  style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control"   name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <br/>
                            </div>

                            <div >
                                <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 5px;margin-bottom: 8px;margin-right: 14px" class="btn btn-facebook pull-right">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```